# Muting 'starting worker' message from foreach in ROUT file

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

My code currently looks like this

```
results= foreach(i=seq(1,n),.combine='c') %dopar% {
               require('Matrix',quietly=TRUE)
               start_time=Sys.time()
               Q[i]=some_function(1,2,3)
               end_time=Sys.time()
               print(end_time-start_time)
   }
```

where I am calculating something in parallel and want to be able to print to the ROUT file inside each parallel process. The problem is my ROUT file is filled with the following

```
starting worker pid=82688 on localhost:11668 at 10:57:10.347
starting worker pid=82672 on localhost:11668 at 10:57:10.347
starting worker pid=82677 on localhost:11668 at 10:57:10.347
starting worker pid=82680 on localhost:11668 at 10:57:10.347
starting worker pid=82669 on localhost:11668 at 10:57:10.346
```

Since my code involves me calling foreach multiple times this makes it very difficult to parse through the ROUT file

Is there a way to mute the "starting worker pid=..." lines from an R outfile in the `foreach` package?